# How to retrieve the number of users who chose "only me" to see my application posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app, and I would like to retrieve the number of
users who chose "Only Me" from the post visibility options.
Someone knows how can I do it?

Best.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get this data directly. There is a [privacy_setting](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/privacy_setting/) FQL table that will let you get the privacy setting that a user has enabled for your application. You could try that table, but what are you trying to achieve out of this ?

Comment: But keep in mind that this will only give you the _default_ privacy setting the user has agreed upon with your app – but that does not hinder the user to select a _different_ setting on a single occasion, for example when using the feed dialog to post something on their wall.